# Long polling with Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, long-polling

I'm developing a chat web app, so of course I need to use some kind of a "push" method to post something if an event happens in the background. I've decided to stick with long-polling for the moment, because I'm kinda new to web development and I don't have a lot of time to learn a good way to push new information to the view, and it seems to work just fine. So, now to my question: In the server side I have a method in which I have a never ending while cycle, with no sleep in it, so if anything happens (e.g. the user gets a new message) I can post it to the view in real time. With a few users, it works fine, but what will happen to the server if a lot of users start to use it? Will it crash?

Code sample:

```
def update() {
 boolean stayInWhile = true
 while(stayInWhile) {
  //check for updates
  if(/*update available*/) {
   stayInWhile = false
   //set up a response
  }
 }
 //return response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, I think the approach you're using could end up starving the container of request threads if lots of people are simultaneously using your application.

A better way to do this might be to run a javascript timer on the client browser that submits an ajax request to your `update()` method every few seconds. That way your request thread will be returned to the pool after each 'check'. Take a look at the [javascript `setTimeout` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). And also a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713484/jquery-progress-bar-settimeout) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079681/update-a-jquery-progress-bar-added-at-runtime) stackoverflow questions about updating a progress bar using setTimeout.

Alternatively, you could set up an ajax 'push' (from server -> client) using the excellent [Grails Atmosphere plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/atmosphere).

Comment: Hi! First: thanks for the response! Second: I've used simple polling with the setTimeout method, but it didn't give me realtime response and it didn't work to well in Chrome. I've did a little research and people are saying that I should be using long polling and not simple polling. I need to know how to make long polling more efficient. As for the Atmosphere plugin, I've heard of it, but as I said, I don't have enough time to learn and implement it.

Comment: I believe Atmosphere plugin is already implemented, you don't need to spend time on it

Comment: I have to spend time on learning how to use Atmosphere. Events push isn't working on my PC... As I said: I need something to make long polling better, not another method.

Comment: The problems are inherent with polling. If you don't want the issues, you need to do something different.